# Does $v(x)$ suffice to show $f \in BV[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed. Here is a proof for Theorem13.5,
[image]

$BV[a,b]$ is the set of functions on $[a,b]$ with bounded variation and $v_a^b$f represents the total variation of function $f$ on $[a,b]$.

For Corollary 13.6, only increasing $v(x)$ will suffice to show $f \in BV[a,b]$, right?

Comment: No, not right: one needs to show that both `v` and `v-f` are nondecreasing.

Comment: @Did: Increasing v(x) sufficiently imply v-f is increasing. See, v(x) is increasing => v(y)-v(x) = $v_x^y$f >= |f(y)-f(x)| >= f(y)-f(x).

Comment: Thus, increasing alone does not suffice. (Do not hesitate to expand on your question. At present, what you are asking exactly is not very clear.)

Comment: @Did: Well. I mean only increasing v(x) does suffice to show  f ∈ BV[a,b] while only increading (v-f) doesn't. This is because increasing v(x) implies increasing (v-f) while the opposite failed.